# Como controlar si un usuario le da permitir o rechazar al permiso de Ubicacion en Android?

Tags: android, apache-cordova

agregué al archivo AndroidManisfest.xml las siguientes lineas:

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Luego al iniciar la app, automaticamente me sale el mensaje:

```
Quieres que la app de ... realice la siguiente acción:
acceso a la ubicación de este dispositivo?
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de como controlar si el usuario le da Permir o Rechazar, por ejemplo si el usuario le da Rechazar entonces que muestre un mensaje de que el permiso es necesario y se cierre la app, hasta que el usuario le de permitir entonces que sí pueda usarla.

PD: Estoy usando Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Con este plugin solucionas tus problemas: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

```
Aca algun ejemplo que podrias usar:

cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized(function(authorized){
    console.log("Location is " + (authorized ? "authorized" : "unauthorized"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```